# how can i set own weekends in react fullcalender?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

How can I set own weekends in react Full Calender. I want to set the weekends to Saturday but by default it is Sunday and Saturday . How can I customize it?

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
      // events={event}
      events={event}
      daysOfWeek={(0, 1)}
      DayGrid={true}
      TimeGrid={true}
      selectMirror={true}
      dayMaxEvents={true}
      headerToolbar={{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay,listWeek',
      }}
      dayClick={(e) => handleDateClick}
      eventAdd={handleDateClick}
      editable={true}
      droppable={true}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the prop you want:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/hiddenDays

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
      // events={event}
      hiddenDays={[6]}
      events={event}
      daysOfWeek={(0, 1)}
      DayGrid={true}
      TimeGrid={true}
      selectMirror={true}
      dayMaxEvents={true}
      daysHidden={[6]}
      headerToolbar={{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay,listWeek',
      }}
      dayClick={(e) => handleDateClick}
      eventAdd={handleDateClick}
      editable={true}
      droppable={true}
    />
```